# solr - execute multiple queries in one request

Tags: solr, union

Is there a way to execute multiple queries in a single solr request and get the union of results as response

my simplified schema would look like a name field and a type field(4-5 different types) and I want 10 results per type value. can this be done in solr?

Comment: Not possible to perform several requests and federate the results client-side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently not possible, Look at this request, possibly when this fix is in place

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1093

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be done w/ Field Collapsing

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing#Quick_Start

Their example is similar except instead of types they are splitting the price into ranges:

> We can find the top documents that also match arbitrary queries with the group.query command (much like facet.query). For example, we could use this to find the top 3 documents with in different price ranges:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?wt=json&indent=true&fl=name,price&q=memory&group=true&group.query=price:[0+TO+99.99]&group.query=price:[100+TO+*]&group.limit=3
```

In your case group.limit=10.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by field *grouping* or field *collapsing*.

For example: (separate lines for readability)

```
http://mysolrhost/select?
&q=*
&fl=name,type
&count=50
&group=true
&group.field=type
&group.limit=10
&group.main=true
```

References:

- https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/result-grouping.html
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/FieldCollapsing#Quick_Start

Related question with additional details:

- [Is it possible to return 10 SOLR docs that match one condition and 10 docs that match another condition for a total of count=20 docs in same query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75815491/is-it-possible-to-return-10-solr-docs-that-match-one-condition-and-10-docs-that?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 0):

[Federated Search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FederatedSearch)

[Distributed Search - needs all the definition schemas to look the same](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch)

Comment: Federated search was renamed as distributed one (for that's what it was apparently), both links point to same page now.