# Solr data-config multiple statements in query

Tags: java, oracle, solr

Solr example:

```
<entity name="item" query="select * from item">
```

If I want to do a query like this:

```
<entity name="item" query="BEGIN some_package.some_function(x,y); END; 

select * from item">
```

how can I achieve this in Solr?  In the event it isn't obvious what I want to do, I want to run `some_function(x,y)` right before I execute the standard `select *` query against my table.  I have achieved similar functionality in JDBC

Comment: This relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388005/solr-execute-multiple-queries-in-one-request

Comment: @xQbert yeah that may be the issue, I instead may need to wrap this in a function and call it.  Good find.