# Searching in two columns

Tags: solr

I have a solr schema consisting of name and idnumber.

- name column stores name of a person
- idnumber stores numbers of passport/driving license ets.

My search condition is like

> Get all results when the name of person is 'ABC' or idnumber is '123'

I used the query

```
(name:'MAHMUD ABID HAMID BID HAMID' OR idnumber:123) 
AND  (name:'MAHMUD' AND name:'ABID AND name:'HAMID' AND name:'BID' AND 
      name:'HAMID' OR idnumber:123)
```

But I am not getting the result as per my requirement.

Comment: What's wrong with just `name:'MAHMUD ABID HAMID BID HAMID' OR idnumber:123`?

Comment: @Amadan when i apply minimum match to name and idnumber i am not getting any results, if the minimum match is for name alone then some results are coming, but not accurate

Comment: Then you misreported your stated requirement. You said "Get all results when the name of person is 'ABC' or idnumber is '123' ". (Also, use backticks - \` - for code quoting, not tags.)

Comment: @Amadan just as we have `UNION` in SQL, is there any method in solr

Comment: No - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388005/solr-execute-multiple-queries-in-one-request . But you can do an almost-union using OR queries. But again, what exactly is it you're trying to do? Find full name, number or partial name, with partial name being less important? Because you just said that what you wrote in your OP was not correct.

Comment: @Amadan what i need is get all names exactly as `MAHMUD ABID HAMID BID HAMID` or all names having `idnumber:123`. if I search as `name:'MAHMUD ABID HAMID BID HAMID' OR idnumber:123` then i get all names having atleast one match

Comment: Oh, ok, finally understood - `name:'MAHMUD ABIT'` is not looking for `MAHMUD ABIT`, but also finding `MAHMUD` only? It might be wrong quotes: 'A phrase is a group of words surrounded by *double quotes* such as `"hello dolly"`'. Try `name:"MAHMUD ABID HAMID BID HAMID" OR idnumber:123`?

Comment: @Amadan: Still there is an issue, if the postion of **firstname** and **lastname** changes as `ABIT MAHMUD` instead of `MAHMUD ABIT` then there is no output.

Comment: There shouldn't be any output, as you said: "what i need is get all names exactly as `MAHMUD ABID HAMID BID HAMID` or all names having `idnumber:123`".  "exactly" is not the same as "having all of the same words in any order". I give up, you can't explain what you want.

Comment: A schema snippet for the field you try to query would increase your chances of getting this answered.